# How to alias enum name and enum values in C#? Intended use is improving code readability

Tags: c#, enums

**Context**

I'm about to spent quite some time working with a C# API. Use of this API will imply the very frequent use of a small set of `enum` from that API (number of values in the hundreds range). These `enum` are sprinkled everywhere in the code.

I dislike the naming of these `enum` as I find they add a lot of noise to the code written. They are named with the following template:

`SoftwareNameNameOfTheKindOfEnum.SoftwareNameNameOfTheKindOfEnumKindOfValue`

A slightly modified but very similar example would be:

`YZBuiltInCategoryKinds.YZBuiltInCategoryKindsOtherCategory`

One enum value takes easily 50 to 60 characters, and I find them hard to read when used in the code.

I'd rather be reading something along:

`NameOfTheKindOfEnum.KindOfValue`

which for the example above would give:

`CategoryKind.OtherCategory`

**Question:**
How to make aliases of `enum` in C#, aliasing not only the `enum` type name, but also the `enum` values names. Aliasing the type name is easy with a `using` directive, but it doesn't affect the `enum` values names.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Replaced `static readonly` by `const` thanks to @MarcGravell comment.

A solution I found is to create a set of `const` variables stored in a `static` class, one for each `enum`, such as:

```cs
public static class CategoryKind
{
    public const YZBuiltInCategoryKinds OtherCategory = YZBuiltInCategoryKinds.YZBuiltInCategoryKindsOtherCategory,
    // etc... add as many readonly variables as there is values for this `enum`
}
```

With these static classes, code like:

```cs
var myProperty = new Property(YZBuiltInPropertyTypes.YZBuiltInPropertyTypesInteger, 10, YZBuiltInCategoryKinds.YZBuiltInCategoryKindsOtherCategory);
```

would become

```cs
var myProperty = new Property(PropertyType.Int, 10, CategoryKind.OtherCategory);
```

Comment: note: `const` would probably be preferable to `readonly` - then it gets burned into consumers directly, rather than being a static field lookup (the JIT *might* still reduce a static readonly field lookup to an inlined const, but it might not - depending on the framework version)

Comment: If you make something like this though, you might as well just make your own enum; enums are consts after all, you can just initialise it with the original enum values. Though I guess then, if they're not just used as `int`, you would need to cast it to pass it on to functions that expect the original enum type...

Comment: @MarcGravell

Thanks, you are right, I'll edit the answer.